# Using Nodejs for pulling data and ajax for sending data

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, node.js

Here is my situation... I am a newby in nodejs and since I have a background of PHP/MySQL , I want to know how to sync the both.. I will give you an example.. Suppose there is a chat box. When someone writes and presses enter, the data will go to the MySQL database with the help of ajax. And I want to fetch that data using nodejs . Ajax or PHP have nothing to do with the fetching. Since nodejs is built basically for realtime application.. I think that just fetching the data with nodejs is the right thing to do.. The sending part can be done with php and ajax..

```
<body>
<div class="fetch_data">
/*Here I want to fetch and show the data using node.*/
</div>
<input type="text" id="chat_text"/>
<input type="button" onclick="sendata();">
</body>
```

Ajax part

```
function sendata(){

var chattext = $('#chat_text').val();

var data = {

action : "send_data",
post : chattext

};

$.ajax({

type : "POST",
data : data,
url : "send_chat.php",
cache : false,
success : function(result){

console.log(result);

}

})

}
```

PHP part..

```
$action = isset($_POST['action']);
if($action == "send_data"){

$chat = $_POST['post'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO `chat_table` VALUES(NULL, :chat)";
$sql_prepare = $db->prepare($sql);
$sql_prepare->bindParam(":chat", $chat);
$sql_prepare->execute();

echo "Successfully entered into the database!";

}
```

Till now it is the sending part done.. I need to open a connection using Node and fetch the data within this : `<div class="fetch_data"></div>`

How do I do that? Help needed. There is not a single clear tutorial that I found that shows how to implement this... Thank You